# Script for Adding AD Users to Microsoft Dynamics 365 Accounts

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamic-sql, dynamics-crm-2013

Does anyone know the best approach to add multiple Active Directory user accounts to user accounts in Microsoft Dynamics 365?  A script or something else, perhaps?

I have a large number of test accounts in AD that I want to add to a test instance of Dynamics 365 that I have for load testing purposes, and was wondering if there was an easy way to do this rather than have to go into the Settings screen of Dynamics and do this manually for each user.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way of doing this in an automated way. Users must have an active directory account, so in any test environment you need to have AD. If you are on prem (which from your tags, I am assuming you are), you could try importing user records from another environment. The AD profiles would have to match.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using On-Line as you mentioned Dynamice 365.

1. To activate User you need license for that particular user.
2. You would need to have that particualr user already availble or
   newly created in Office 365.
3. Once you have that user in Office 365 you could assign the user
   License.
4. After assigning license you will need to provide proper security
       role and business unit.

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNRCAYiTrjA&feature=youtu.be

There are different ways you could create new user in Office 365.

To add multiple users at the same time, follow these steps:

1. Use a spreadsheet to add people in bulk. See Add several users at
   the same time.
2. Automate adding accounts and assigning licenses. See Create user accounts with Office 365 PowerShell. Choose this method if you're already familiar with using Windows PowerShell cmdlets.
3. Using ActiveDirectory? Set up directory synchronization for Office 365. Use the Azure AD Connect tool to replicate Active Directory user accounts (and other Active Directory objects) in Office 365. The sync only adds the user accounts. You will need to assign
   licenses to the synced users before they can use email and other
   Office apps.
4. Migrating from Exchange? Ways to migrate multiple email accounts to
   Office 365. When you migrate multiple mailboxes to Office 365 by
   using either cutover, staged, or a hybrid Exchange method, you will
   add users automatically as part of the migration. The migration only
   adds the user accounts. You will need assign licenses to the users
   before they can use email and other Office apps.

Ref from Microsoft Docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/add-users?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-US%252fArticle%252fCreate-or-edit-users-in-Office-365-1970f7d6-03b5-442f-b385-5880b9c256ec&view=o365-worldwide